# Create a column based on the substring of another column using case_when

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, case

I had this dataframe of one column. I created a new column `filenum` using `case_when` as follow

```
library(tidyverse)
filename <- c('./1_test1', './1_test2', 
              './2_test1', './2_test2', 
              './3_test1', './3_test2')
df <- data.frame(filename)
df <- test %>% mutate(filenum = case_when(
  length(grep('./1', df$filename)) > 0 ~ 1,
  length(grep('./2', df$filename)) > 0 ~ 2,
  length(grep('./3', df$filename)) > 0 ~ 3,
  )
)
```

I expected the dataframe would become

```
   filename filenum
1 ./1_test1       1
2 ./1_test2       1
3 ./2_test1       2
4 ./2_test2       2
5 ./3_test1       3
6 ./3_test2       3
```

However, I got this result

```
   filename filenum
1 ./1_test1       1
2 ./1_test2       1
3 ./2_test1       1
4 ./2_test2       1
5 ./3_test1       1
6 ./3_test2       1
```

My questions are:

1. What did I do wrong?
2. Is there a better way to create a new column based on the substring of an existing column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grepl` instead of `grep`, which output logical values. In this way, you don't need to set `length(...) > 0`. Also, you don't need to use the `df$` syntax to refer to columns in `dplyr`, just the column name itself is enough.

Moreover, a dot `.` means any character in regex in `grepl`, so you better escape it, or use the `fixed = TRUE` parameter. The complete code should be:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(filenum = case_when(grepl('./1', filename, fixed = T) ~ 1, 
                             grepl('./2', filename, fixed = T) ~ 2, 
                             grepl('./3', filename, fixed = T) ~ 3))
```

---

Or do it with `sub` if you want to extract the digit after the `/` symbol and before `_`.

Regex explanation:

1. Since `.` means any character in regular expression (regex), we need to "escape" it so that R knows we are referring to the literal dot character by adding double slashes before it `\\.`.
2. `\\d` is another regex element which means digit, we put a plus sign `+` after it to indicate one or more digits.
3. You can see that `(\\d+)` is wrapped in brackets, which indicates a regex capture group.
4. Use `\\1` to refer back to this capture group as the replacement pattern in `sub`.

```r
df %>% mutate(filenum = sub("\\./(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", filename))
```

#### Output

```
   filename filenum
1 ./1_test1       1
2 ./1_test2       1
3 ./2_test1       2
4 ./2_test2       2
5 ./3_test1       3
6 ./3_test2       3
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. So, `case_when` requires the left hand side of the equation/expression `~` to be a Boolean value for it to work properly? My mistake was that everything in the left hand side returned value of 1, thus, the wrong result?

Comment: @Nemo You are correct that `case_when` requires logical values on the LHS, your code also output logical value, but they're not row specific. So from your code, if you do `length(grep('./1', df$filename)) > 0`, it only returns a single `TRUE` value, therefore the first expression of your `case_when` would be executed for all rows, and thus all would be set to `1`

Comment: @Nemo On the other hand, if you do my code, for example `grepl('./1', df$filename, fixed = T)`, the output would be `[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`, each logical value corresponds to one row.

Comment: I think the `sub(...)` option in your answer is more succinct than `case_when` in this scenario. But why do we need double backward slash in `\\.`, `\\d+` and what did `\\1` refer to

Comment: @Nemo Added some explanation for the regex :)